# Plot sf points with ggmap in bgMap parameter is not working

Tags: r, r-sf

I'm trying to plot a sf object with a ggmap object, following instructions I found [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/336).

The code I'm using is below:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

url_base <- "http://dados.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/"
dat <- "dataset/8da55b0e-b385-4b54-9296-d0000014ddd5/"
rec <- "resource/dfa2e046-b975-4ff5-983f-dacfd8cb06b2/"
arq <- "download/escolasr34dez2017.csv"

path <- paste0(url_base, dat, rec, arq)
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
download.file(path, tmp)
escolas <- read.csv(tmp, sep = ";")

escolas_sf <- st_as_sf(select(filter(escolas, !is.na(LONGITUDE)), TIPOESC, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE),
                       coords = c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE")) %>%
  st_set_crs(31983)

plot(escolas_sf)

map_sp <- ggmap::get_map("Cidade de São Paulo", zoom = 10)
plot(map_sp)
```

Everything works till here. I don't know why, but the map pasted in `bgMap` do not show. I can see only the points, which are stored on the sf object.

```
plot(st_transform(escolas_sf, 3857), col = "blue", bgMap = map_sp)
```

Can anyone help me to understand why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible that you have the wrong projection? Are you sure it's epsg 31983